# What does "sparse" mean in the context of neural nets?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I've seen "sparse" and "sparsity" used in a way that suggests it's something that improves a model's accuracy. For example:

> I think the unsupervised phase might be not so important if some
>   sparse connections or neurons are used, such as rectifier units or
>   convolutional connection, and big training data is available.

From https://www.quora.com/When-does-unsupervised-pre-training-improve-classification-accuracy-for-a-deep-neural-network-When-does-it-not

What does "sparse" mean in this context?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Sparsity means most of the weights are 0. This can lead to an increase in space and time efficiency.

---

**Detailed version**: In general, neural networks are represented as tensors. Each layer of neurons is represented by a matrix. Each entry in the matrix can be thought of as representative of the connection between two neurons. In a simple neural network, like a classic feed-forward neural network, every neuron on a given layer is connected to every neuron on the subsequent layer. This means that each layer must have *n<sup>2</sup>* connections represented, where *n* is the size of both of the layers. In large networks, this can take a lot of memory and time to propagate. Since different parts of a neural network often work on different subtasks, it can be unnecessary for every neuron to be connected to every neuron in the next layer. In fact, it might make sense for a neural network to have most pairs of neurons with a connection weight of 0. Training a neural network might result in these less significant connection weights adopting values very close to 0 but accuracy would not be significantly affected if the values were exactly 0.

A matrix in which most entries are 0 is called a sparse matrix. These matrices can be stored more efficiently and certain computations can be carried out more efficiently on them provided the matrix is sufficiently large and sparse. Neural networks can leverage the efficiency gained from sparsity by assuming most connection weights are equal to 0.

I must say that neural networks are a complex and diverse topic. There are a lot of approaches used. There are certain kinds of neural networks with different morphologies than the simple layer connections I referenced above. Sparsity can be leveraged in many types of neural networks since matrices are fairly universal to neural network representation.

Comment: Although it is good that you explained it in detail, I would like to see a TL;DR: "A lot of 0s in the weight matrices."

Comment: Is this similar as LASSO?

Answer (score 2):

Sparse, as can be deduced from the meaning in layman English refers to sparsity in the connections between neurons, basically, the weights have non-significant values (close to 0)
In some cases it might also refer to cases where we do not have all connections and very less connections itself (less weights)